# How to override the renderer_classes to send extra information in REST API

Tags: django, authentication, django-rest-framework, renderer

I have created the rest api for authentication of user, and in the response I am getting the token. I also want to add whether the user has staff permission or not, I have already got the information is serializers but I am not able to pass to the view.

And I need to authentication whether user is active or not This part is not working at all.

My serializer code :

```
class AuthTokenSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    """Serializer for the user authentication object"""
    email = serializers.CharField()
    password = serializers.CharField(
        style={'input_type': 'password'},
        trim_whitespace=False
    )

    def validate(self, attrs):
        """Validate and authenticate the user"""
        email = attrs.get('email')
        password = attrs.get('password')

        user = authenticate(
            request=self.context.get('request'),
            username=email,
            password=password
        )
#This part I am trying to authenticate whether the account is active or not 
        if user is not None:
            if not user.is_active:
                msg = _('The password is valid, but the account has been disabled! ')
                raise serializers.ValidationError(msg, code='not_active')

        if not user:
            msg = _('Unable to authenticate with provided credentials')
            raise serializers.ValidationError(msg, code='authorization')

        attrs['user'] = user
        attrs['is_staff'] = user.is_staff  #Here I am getting the user has permission of staff or not.
        return attrs
```

And the views.py is :

```
class CreateTokenView(ObtainAuthToken):
    """Create a new auth token for the user"""
    serializer_class = AuthTokenSerializer
    renderer_classes = api_settings.DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES
```

models.py

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    """Custom user model that supports using email instead of username"""
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, upload_to=user_image_file_path)
    contact_no = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='')
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
```

How i can override my views so that I can get these two information. Any information will be great help. Thank you

Comment: Do you want to return JSON response?

Comment: @EmdadulSawon Yes. I want to return JSON response currently I am getting only token

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are want to change the default behavior of post response, you need to explicitly change that.

So how we can achieve that. We need to overwrite the `post` method of `ObtainAuthToken`. I hope following code will solve your problem.

```
from rest_framework.authtoken.views import ObtainAuthToken
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token
from rest_framework.response import Response

class CreateTokenView(ObtainAuthToken):
    serializer_class = AuthTokenSerializer
    renderer_classes = api_settings.DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data,
                                           context={'request': request})
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        user = serializer.validated_data['user']
        token, created = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
        return Response({
            'token': token.key,
            'is_staff': user.is_staff
        })
```

References: 
[django-restframework example](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#generating-tokens)

Comment: Its work as expected. But why we are using created variable. I did'nt got part

Comment: get_or_create returns tuple, first one is object and second one is boolean created or not. so explicitly two variable needed here.

Comment: And How I will check if the user is active or not, Because my code is not working there

Comment: @Piyush what i can see, you properly raise validation error in serializer if user is not active. So thats should not a problem here.

Comment: But that's not working. If user is inactive the response "Unable to authenticate with provided credentials"

Comment: remove ( request=self.context.get('request'), ) from authenticate function argument. 
authenticate should have username and password. If i amnot wrong.

Comment: @Piyush can you update your question with your User model. Seems like you change it.  There must mention `USERNAME_FIELD = 'email``.

Comment: I have added it. Please check